# mopabootstrap bundle and symfony2 issue

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [mopabootstrap bundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle), followed all of the instructions. I am getting the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js".") in "MopaBootstrapBundle::base.html.twig".
```

I found the thread here that seems to have an answer to my [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/Z6PDpimBzMk) as well, but i tried it and it still gives me the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of MopaBootstrap, and Symfony 2.1 or 2.2, it seems that the `twitter/bootstrap` files aren't correctly installed and symlinked.

Maybe you have missed the `composer.json` part:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    }
}
```

[from the MopaBootstrap doc](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-installation.md)

Those commands create the symlink from the vendors folder: `/vendor/twitter/bootstrap`
to the MopaBootstrap folder:

```
/vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/bootstrap
```

---

Be sure to also install twitter/bootstrap in your composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "dev-master"
    }
}
```